# object play is not a member of package reactivemongo

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4, reactivemongo

```
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json._
import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection._
import play.modules.reactivemongo.{
MongoController, ReactiveMongoApi, ReactiveMongoComponents
}
import reactivemongo.play.json._, collection.JSONCollection
import reactivemongo.api.QueryOpts
import reactivemongo.bson.BSONObjectID
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := """sample"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Atlassian Releases" at "https://maven.atlassian.com/public/",
  "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
  "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

)

pipelineStages := Seq(digest,gzip)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  filters,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1",
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette" % "3.0.0",
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0",
  "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.0.0",
  "net.ceedubs" %% "ficus" % "1.1.2",
  "com.adrianhurt" %% "play-bootstrap3" % "0.4.4-P24",
  "com.mohiva" %% "play-silhouette-testkit" % "3.0.0" % "test",
  "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.11.7.play24",
  specs2 % Test
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-encoding", "UTF-8",
  "-deprecation",
  "-feature",
  "-unchecked",
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
  "-Xlint",
  "-Ywarn-adapted-args",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-Ywarn-inaccessible",
  "-Ywarn-nullary-override",
  "-Ywarn-value-discard",
  "-language:reflectiveCalls"
)
```

**plugin.sbt**

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")

// web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-gzip" % "1.0.0")
```

Comment: try doing sbt refress from your IDE, it should work or try re-importing project in IDE.

Comment: Thank for your reply.

Comment: Try not using IDE. I just run `sbt` in command line and type `run` in sbt CLI. It works